# Move woocommerce directory

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We have a site that has an website already that does not use Wordpress https://subdomain.example.com.

Setup Wordpress and Woocommerce in a subdirectory https://subdomain.example.com/shop

Configured Woocommerce using it's wizard and then tried opening it.

Going to shop it now shows the url as

https://subdmomain.example.com/shop/shop

How do I move Woocommerce as Wordpress root in https://subdomain.example.com/shop?

Answer (score 0):

Installed Wordpress on the site directory instead, I thought this would conflict files like index.html with index.php redirects back to the indedx.html site. Turns out it works seamlessly.

Shop is now at https://subdomain.example.com/shop